# three.js - THREE.MeshFaceMaterial update textures on cube

Tags: three.js, mesh, cube

Using r54:

cube and on each side a different texture.

```
var materials = [new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: textureSmallSide}),
                 new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: textureSmallSide}), 
                 new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: textureSmallSide}),
                 new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: textureSmallSide}),
                 new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture}),
                 new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture})];
```

so in this case 6 different canvas-obj

```
new THREE.Mesh(cuboidgeo, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
```

question: 
how can I get the materials array to update these textures(e.g change values of the canvas-obj)? 
I know that when I create a mesh like that:

```
new THREE.Mesh(cubegeo, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture}));
```

I can get my canvas object like:

```
cubemeshobj.material.map.image
```

but who do I get the textures(material array) of THREE.MeshFaceMaterial ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your object in console. Now you have an array of materials

```
for(var i = 0; i < cubemeshobj.material.materials.length; i++){

      cubemeshobj.material.materials[i].map.image;

}
```

r56